# PostgreSQL: Should I alter an existing index or create a new one?

Tags: postgresql

I have a billing_infos table that has a column called `order_id`. It already has an index.

```
\d billing_infos
...
Indexes:
    "billing_infos_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "billing_infos_address_id_idx" btree (address_id)
    "index_billing_infos_on_order_id" btree (order_id) //<--this one
```

However, I am not sure if this is a unique index. I have the task of making a unique index, but I'm not sure if I should change the one that's already there or create a new one. The order_id values should all be unique.

Should I create a new index or alter the existing one?
And how do I check to see if the existing indexes are unique?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is probably least invasive to create a unique index concurrently. Note that using a CONSTRAINT is the recommended way to enforce uniqueness. A UNIQUE index is more useful if the columns being checked require a function to create the uniqueness. An example of the latter is using COALESCE() to prevent NULLs from bypassing the UNIQUE check.
Eg.

```
create unique index foo_col1_col2_uidx on foo (col1, coalesce(col2,-1));
```

In the example above, col2 is an integer column and is *not* defined as NOT NULL.

Example of creating unique index concurrently.

```
create unique index concurrently billing_infos_order_id_uidx on billing_infos (order_id);
```

The output in `psql` from `\d` for a UNIQUE index (I've named mine _uidx) and UNIQUE CONSTRAINT (_uc) looks like the following:

```
\d foo
                Table "public.foo"
 Column |            Type             | Modifiers 
--------+-----------------------------+-----------
 x      | integer                     | 
 tstamp | timestamp without time zone | 
 col    | text                        | 
Indexes:
    "foo_col_uidx" UNIQUE, btree (col)                <<< unique index
    "foo_tstamp_uc" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (tstamp) <<< unique constraint
    "foo_idx" btree (x)
```

Answer (score 1):

That is not a unique index.

Try creating a simple table which has a primary key, a column with a unique constraint, and a column with a normal index:

```
create table example (id integer primary key, alpha integer, beta integer, gamma integer);
alter table example add constraint alpha_unique unique (alpha);
create index beta_normal on example (beta);
create unique index gamma_unique on example (gamma);
```

If you use `\d` on it, the output is:

```
    Table "public.example"
 Column |  Type   | Modifiers 
--------+---------+-----------
 id     | integer | not null
 alpha  | integer | 
 beta   | integer | 
 gamma  | integer | 
Indexes:
    "example_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (id)
    "alpha_unique" UNIQUE CONSTRAINT, btree (alpha)
    "gamma_unique" UNIQUE, btree (gamma)
    "beta_normal" btree (beta)
```

As you can see, when an index is unique, it says so. You can even see when the index implements a unique constraint.

So, what should you do? Firstly, don't add a unique index. Don't ever do that. If you want to impose a uniqueness constraint on a column, you do that by adding a unique constraint. A constraint, not an index. The clue is in the name.

Adding a unique index may well work, but it is the wrong thing to do as the [PostgreSQL manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/indexes-unique.html) says:

> The preferred way to add a unique constraint to a table is ALTER TABLE
>   ... ADD CONSTRAINT. The use of indexes to enforce unique constraints
>   could be considered an implementation detail that should not be
>   accessed directly.

So, simply use the `alter table ... add constraint` syntax i use above to add the constraint.

Comment: Great tip at the end. I'll go with the constraint

Comment: No problem. IIRC, Oracle doesn't distinguish between unique constraints and indexes, so the normal way to add a unique constraint is to add a unique index. Do you have an Oracle background? Or is it SQL Server i'm thinking of?

Answer (score 0):

Use PgAdmin tool to see the index structure.